# How to set Paypal Website Standard New Order Status as Complete instead of Processing?

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, order-status

I have a problem with my `new order status` when using Paypal website payment standard. When payment is complete with PayPal, it sets the order status to `processing` while I want it to be `complete`.

The payment works fine. The problem is that the order status is stuck in processing. Of course I Know i could set it to complete manually.

How do I get it so that orders are automatically set to complete? i.e. I don’t want to do so this manually, each time an order is complete via PalPal, I want the status to be “`complete`”.

The above content is mostly from an old post from a couple of years ago, no one really answered this question.

Answer (score 0):

As per magento system,if you want to change an order status to complete,

Then Order should be `have invoice and shipment`,so you need `create to invoice and shipment first then status will automatically change to completed`.Without create invoice and shipment,order status could not chnageto complete.

See [How to Programmatically create Shipment of a new order in magento](https://www.amitbera.com/programmatically-create-shipment-of-a-new-order-in-magento/)

And [Programmatically create invoice of a new order in magento](http://www.amitbera.com/programmatically-create-invoice-of-a-new-order-in-magento/)

Comment: Thanks for the rely. I dont want to mannully change the new order status to be complete, i already to know how to do that. what i want is make every successfully paid order status to be complete, instead of the default processing. Since on our website and apps, the order status has to be complete so that an SMS could be sent to the user.